# has_child not working as expected inside has_parent,

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have a parent child relationship in my elasticsearch 7.9 where I am having the **car** as a parent type and it has multiple child types like **honda, suzuki, volvo** now I want to have a child of type volvo and parent type is car.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "car",
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "volvo",
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is returning the objects having **child type** honda as well.
Where I am wrong ?
Thanks.

- what should be the query where I want the parent_type car with an id xxxxx and child is volvo.

**Updated**

Here is the mapping.

```json
{
  "car": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "_class": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "made": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "relation": {
          "type": "join",
          "eager_global_ordinals": true,
          "relations": {
            "car": ["volvo", "suzuki", "honda"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your mapping? That'd would help!

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal updated with the mapping.